# silex form without twig

Tags: php, symfony1, smarty, silex

I'm using silex with a legacy application with a lot of smarty templates and also want to use the Form Provider, but the documentation has only an example to use this with Twig.

Does anyone has a small example how to render the Form to a variable that can then be displayed in a smarty template

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#form-rendering-template you can render the form manually in php

Comment: i tried this but this uses the symfony view object that i don't have in silex

Comment: did you try passing array('view' => $form->createView()) and accessing that object.

Comment: @ThomasNiepraschk is your project Open Source? What Silex extension are you using to support Smarty? [FractalizeR](http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_638/smarty-extention-for-silex-framework/)? I'm the author of [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle) and I'm interested in integrating Symfony-2.1 Form so it would be nice to follow your project if possible.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is, that you can not render a form only by the symfony form classes.
Those classes do not have the functionality to render the form.
You need some templates that do the rendering. Those templates can be PHP or Twig.
Here is a example how to get the Form as HTML which you could then pass to the smarty template:

```
$html .= $silex['twig']->render('template.twig', array(
        'form'         => $form->createView
    ));

$smarty->assign('form_html',$html);
```